# Is "Ring Signature" used in "Confidential Transactions" of the Bitcoin?

Tags: monero, confidential-transactions

According to the **Ring Confidential Transactions** research paper of **Monero** ([Link to the paper](http://file:///C:/Users/KX5710/Downloads/34-394-1-PB.pdf)), in section ***1.5. Ring Confidential Transactions Overview***, it is mentioned:

> "We describe a modification to the Monero protocol, a proof-of-work
>   cryptocurrency extending the original CryptoNote protocol. The
>   modification is based on **Confidential Transactions** which are used on
>   the Elements side-chain in **Bitcoin**, **except** it **allows** for their use in
>   **ring signatures**  [[cited to this article as reference]](https://people.xiph.org/~greg/confidential_values.txt). Therefore, the modification is given the obvious
>   name of **Ring Confidential Transactions** (Ring CT) for Monero."

However, in the cited article ([Link](https://people.xiph.org/~greg/confidential_values.txt)), it is mentioned that the **Ring** signature is used in **Confidential Transactions of Bitcoin too**.

If so, why in Monero's paper it is mentioned that *"**except** it allows for their use in ring signatures"* as its **difference** with **Bitcoin Confidential Transactions** ?

Is "**Ring** Confidential Transactions" used in both Bitcoin and Monero?

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin does not have confidential transactions.

Comment: I mean this feature: https://people.xiph.org/~greg/confidential_values.txt 
where, it's talking about **Confidential Transactions** as a cryptographic tool to improve the privacy and security of Bitcoin. Apparently, it's written by you :)

Comment: @Questioner Yes, a writeup of a technique exists which could be used in theory, but it's not even a proposal, much less in use, so the question makes no sense.